# My object seems to be traveling through time into the future?

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: Sorry, didn't realize the console updates the object in real time.

I have a controller which, upon being constructed, sets $scope.unit equal to a new object. Then, I console.log the current date, and console.log the object. This should print the current date and a BLANK object to the console.

Below that, I have a $timeout function which is delayed by 7 seconds, where I set the date property to the current date. I then log the current date, and log the unit again.
I would expect the following results in the console window:

```
Sep 12 2016 11:39:27 GMT
Object{}
Sep 12 2016 11:39:34 GMT
Object{ date: Sep 12 2016 11:39:34 GMT }
```

Instead, the date property somehow travels through time, and I get the following:

```
Sep 12 2016 11:39:27 GMT
Object{ date: Sep 12 2016 11:39:34 GMT }
Sep 12 2016 11:39:34 GMT
Object{ date: Sep 12 2016 11:39:34 GMT }
```

If I up the interval from 7 to 8 seconds, it works as expected.  This happens for anything 7 seconds and below.

Code example is below

```
angular.module('test').controller('$scope', [function ($scope){
$scope.unit = {};
console.log(new Date());
console.log($scope.unit);
    $timeout(function () {
      $scope.unit.sensor_data = new Date(); // Data from sensors attached to this unit
      console.log(new Date());
      console.log($scope.unit);
    }, 7000);
 }]);
```

Comment: The console does that when you log objects. The value you see is it's value when you expand it, not the value when it was logged.

Comment: Ah oops.  Well that is good to know.  Thanks